# Configure Npgsql for pascal case

Tags: .net, postgresql

is there any way how to setup Npgsql to convert names to snake_case from pascal case?

Entity

```
class Example {
public long Id;
}
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE example (id int);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, see https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/table-column-naming.html

Just call `.UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention()` after your UseNpgsql call.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseNpgsql(...)
        .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
```

Note that you can also use the `[Column(...)]` attribute in case the automatic conversion produces something you don't like